# Supabase is returning blank when I search for a specific row that I know exists

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, supabase

I'm searching for a specific row in my database table in Supabase but it's returning `[]` for some reason. Here's my code:

```
def check_if_connection_exists(collection_name: str):
    supabase_url = os.environ.get(
        "SUPABASE_URL") + "/rest/v1/my_table"
    supabase_key = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_KEY")
    response = requests.get(
        url=supabase_url + f"?name=eq.{collection_name}&select=*",
        headers={
            "apikey": supabase_key,
            "authorization": "Bearer " + supabase_key,
        },
    )

    if (response.status_code != 200):
        raise Exception(response.json())

    if (response.json() == []):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I've also tried doing this to see if there's any difference between the stored `collection_name` and the one I'm passing into the function: `print(stored_collection_name == collection_name_passed_in_function)`

The `print` call returns true, and when searching through the DB directly, I can also find the row record it refers to.

RLS is disabled and this only happens for a specific value for the `collection_name` for some reason

Comment: Does `collection_name` contain any characters that would require url escaping?

Comment: It's probably better to use the `params` argument to `requests.get()`, instead of adding stuff onto the end of the url.  Try this `requests.get(supabase_url, params={'name': f'eq.{collection_name}', 'select': '*'}, headers=...)`

Comment: Are you sure `name=eq.foo` is the correct query syntax?  Can you link to some documentation showing examples like this?

Comment: _this only happens for a specific value for the collection_name_ So you're saying that this exact code works fine, when you pass in some other value of `collection_name` ?

Comment: Hi, John! Using `params` works! Thanks 